# Efficient way to tokenize a string - C

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to tokenize a string. I have a table of available tokens ordered in the form of a *trie*. Each token knows it has children. A simple tokens table will look like,

```
pattern    value         has_children
--------   ------        --------
s          s-val         1
stack      stack-val     0
over       over-val      1
overflow   overflow-val  0
```

In this table, `stack` is a child of `s` and `overflow` is a child of `over`. In practice, this table will have 5000+ records ordered in this way.

Now, given a string `stackover`, it should output `stack-valover-val`. Algorithm is greedy and it will try to find the longest match always.

To do this, I will start reading each character from the input, look for match, if a match found and the token has children, look for match again by including next character. Do this until we find the longest match. If no match found, try to match by including the next character until we reach the end of string or a successful match.

If we reached end of the string without a match, output `?` symbol and remove the first character from the input. Repeat the whole process with remaining characters.

This algorithm works, but the backtracking and iterating on all possible combinations of the input makes it slow and complex.

I am wondering is there a better way of solving this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why I am keeping track of children : If I found a match and look for longest match, I don't have to do it if the token has no children. This improves the efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of backtracking you could keep in memory all possible results, until one result singles out at certain point in input stream. Example

Tokens: S STACK STACKOVERFLOW STAG OVER OVERFLOW
String: SSTACKOVERFUN

1 - Found S on place 0, have tokens that begin with S, try them all, only S is valid, so **resolve S**
2 - S on 1, have such tokens, try them, possible valid are S and STACK. Don't resolve, just keep them in mind.
3 - T on 2, have no such tokens, so S could be resolved now, but we also have longer token (STACK) so S is no good. Ditch S, and STACK is only left, but it has children. Try string for children. There are no possible children so **resolve STACK**
4 - O on 6, have such tokens, try them, have only OVER, so **resolve OVER**
5 - F on 10, no such tokens, and nothing to resolve from before so this is non-tokenizable
6 and 7 - same as step 5

Final result: S STACK OVER fun

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm?  It creates an automaton to search a keyword tree (trie).

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that you want to take all of your keywords and sort them reverse alphabetically, so your list would become (plus a few extras)

```
0 stack      1
1 s          0
2 overflow   3
3 over       5
4 ovum       5
5 o          0
6 exchange   7
7 ex         0
```

The third column of this list are pointers to the parent token which is always lower on the list.  Then you can take your target string and binary search where it fits on this list.  If it lands above a token which matches then you clip off that portion and repeat the process for the remainder.  If it doesn't match you use the parent pointer to find the next longest potential matching token.

If you want to get really fancy you can also chunk up the strings into 64bit words and compare 8 characters at once in the binary search.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/), It can generate efficient scanners that can do longest match/backtracking. See chapter 6.3 in the [Ragel user guide](http://www.complang.org/ragel/ragel-guide-6.6.pdf) for more information.

I've created a tiny test which I think matches your specification, this is only the state machine description, without the code to feed input:

```
%%{
machine test;

main := |*
's' => { puts("s-val");};
'stack' => { puts("stack-val");};
'over' => { puts("over-val");};
'overflow' => { puts("overflow-val");};

# Anything else matches to any, outputs a '?' and continues
any => {putc('?');};
*|;
}%%
```

Answer (score 0):

[The following token_tree code is based on the prefix_tree class from ZeroMQ](http://github.com/zeromq/zeromq2/blob/v2.0.10/src/prefix_tree.cpp)

The prefix_tree class only returns "true" when one of the tree's prefixes matches the start of the input text.  It will not even tell you which prefix or how long that prefix was.

This token_tree will look for the longest token that matches the start of the input text.  The search
function token_tree_longest_token() only needs to return the length of the longest token matched
against the start of the input text.

The basic algorithm is similar to the one described in the question, but it's implmentation might be faster.

Also there are some ways to improve memory usage, which could have it faster.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* #define TEST_TOKEN_TREE */
/*
 * TODO: possible improvements, use multiple types of nodes: string/branch/leaf.
 * The string node would replace a chain of normal token_nodes and save memory.
 * This would require spliting a node to add branch points.
 * Use these structs:
 * struct token_node {
 *   uint32_t ref_count;
 *   uint8_t  node_type; -- node is token_node_str/token_node_branch/token_node_leaf
 * };
 * struct token_node_str {
 *   token_node base;
 *   uint8_t    reserved;
 *   uint16_t   len;          -- string length
 *   token_node *child;       -- string nodes can only have one child.
 *   uint8_t    str[0];       -- embedded string (not null-terminated)
 * };
 * struct token_node_branch {
 *   token_node base;
 *   uint8_t  min;            -- smallest char in child list.
 *   uint16_t count;          -- child count.
 *   token_node *children[0];
 * };
 * struct token_node_leaf { -- leaf nodes have no children.
 *   token_node base;
 * };
 * This will save memory, but will make code much more complex.
 */

typedef struct token_tree token_tree;
typedef struct token_node token_node;

struct token_tree {
    token_node *root; /**< root node of token tree. */
};

struct token_node {
    uint32_t   ref_count;    /**< how many token references end at this node. */
    uint8_t    min;          /**< smallest 'char' in children's list. */
    uint8_t    reserved;     /**< padding. */
    uint16_t   count;        /**< number of children. (max count = 256, so count must be 16bits) */
    token_node *children[0]; /**< list of children nodes.  index by (c - min) */
};

#define NODE_SIZE(count) (sizeof(token_node) + (sizeof(token_node *) * count))

static token_node *token_node_new(uint16_t count) {
    token_node *node = calloc(1, NODE_SIZE(count));
    node->count = count;
    return node;
}

static void token_node_build_chain(token_node **pnode, const uint8_t *token, size_t len) {
    token_node *node;
    do {
        /* the last node in the chain will have no children. */
        node = token_node_new((len == 0) ? 0 : 1);
        *pnode = node; /* add node to slot in parent's children list. */
        if(len == 0) break;
        /* new node will have one child. */
        node->min = *token;
        node->count = 1;
        /* slot where next node will be saved. */
        pnode = &(node->children[0]);
        /* consume char. */
        token++;
        len--;
    } while(1);
    /* mark last node as end of a valid token. */
    node->ref_count++;
}

static void token_node_free(token_node *node) {
    uint32_t i;
    uint32_t count = node->count;

    /* free children nodes. */
    for(i=0; i < count; i++) {
        if(node->children[i]) token_node_free(node->children[i]);
    }
    free(node);
}

static void token_node_grow(token_node **pnode, uint8_t c) {
    token_node *node = *pnode;
    token_node **children;
    uint8_t  old_min = node->min;
    uint16_t old_count = node->count;
    uint32_t i;
    uint8_t  min;
    uint16_t count;

    if(c < old_min) {
        min = c;
        count = old_count + (old_min - min);
    } else {
        if(old_count == 0) {
            /* the list was empty, so this is the first char. */
            old_min = c;
        }
        min = old_min;
        c -= old_min;
        if(c < old_count) {
            /* don't need to grow. */
            return;
        }
        count = c + 1;
    }

    node = realloc(node, NODE_SIZE(count));
    *pnode = node;
    children = node->children;
    /* if the 'min' value changed, then we need to move all the old slots up. */
    if(old_min != min) {
        uint32_t diff = old_min - min;
        for(i=count-1; i >= diff; i--) {
            children[i] = children[i - diff];
        }
        /* null new slots at start of children list. */
        for(i=0; i < diff; i++) {
            children[i] = NULL;
        }
    } else {
        /* null new slots at end of children list. */
        for(i=old_count; i < count; i++) {
            children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    node->min = min;
    node->count = count;
}

static token_node **token_node_find_last_node(token_node **pnode, const uint8_t **ptoken, size_t *plen) {
    const uint8_t *token = *ptoken;
    size_t len = *plen;
    uint32_t c;
    token_node *node = *pnode;

    while(node && len) {
        /* next char. */
        c = (*token);
        /* if c < node->min, then it will underflow and be > node->count. */
        c -= node->min;
        /* make sure c is in range. */
        if(c >= node->count) {
            /*
             * NOTE: we don't consume this char and "*pnode" will not be null.
             * When adding tokens, this node will be grown to hold more children.
             */
            break;
        }

        /* consume char. */
        token++;
        len--;
        /* get pointer to next node's slot. */
        pnode = &(node->children[c]);
        node = *pnode;
    }

    *ptoken = token;
    *plen = len;
    /* return pointer to last node's slot. */
    return pnode;
}

static void token_node_add(token_node **pnode, const uint8_t *token, size_t len) {
    token_node *node;

    /* find last node in chain for this token. */
    pnode = token_node_find_last_node(pnode, &token, &len);

    /* if full token was consumed then we found the last node for this token. */
    if(!len) {
        node = *pnode;
        node->ref_count++;
        return;
    }

    /* check if the children list of the last node needs to be grown. */
    node = *pnode;
    if(node) {
        uint32_t c = *token;
        /* consume char. */
        token++;
        len--;
        /* grow node to make room for new char. */
        token_node_grow(pnode, c);
        node = *pnode; /* token_node_grow() may change the node's pointer. */
        /* get slot for new child. */
        pnode = &(node->children[c - node->min]);
    }
    /* build node chain for un-consumed part of token. */
    token_node_build_chain(pnode, token, len);
}

static size_t token_node_longest_token(token_node *node, const uint8_t *text, size_t len) {
    size_t last_token_len = 0;
    size_t off = 0;
    uint32_t c;

    /* loop until we get a NULL node or run out of text. */
    do {
        if(node->ref_count > 0) {
            /* found a token, keep track of it's length. */
            last_token_len = off;
        }
        /* end of input text. */
        if(off >= len) break;
        /* next char. */
        c = text[off];
        /* if c < node->min, then it will underflow and be > node->count. */
        c -= node->min;
        /* make sure c is in range. */
        if(c >= node->count) {
            /* End of search, no more child nodes. */
            break;
        }

        /* consume char. */
        off++;
        /* get pointer to next node's slot. */
        node = node->children[c];
    } while(node);

    /* return length of largest token found. */
    return last_token_len;
}

extern token_tree *token_tree_new() {
    token_tree *tree = malloc(sizeof(token_tree));
    tree->root = token_node_new(0);
    return tree;
}

extern void token_tree_free(token_tree *tree) {
    token_node_free(tree->root);
    free(tree);
}

extern void token_tree_add(token_tree *tree, const char *token, size_t len) {
    token_node_add(&(tree->root), token, len);
}

extern size_t token_tree_longest_token(token_tree *tree, const char *text, size_t len) {
    return token_node_longest_token(tree->root, text, len);
}

#ifdef TEST_TOKEN_TREE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char *test_tokens[] = {
    "s",
    "stack",
    "stackoverflow",
    "over",
    "overflow",
    NULL,
};

static const char *test_input[] = {
    "aastackoverasdfasdf",
    "stack7777",
    "777stack777",
    "overstackflow",
    NULL,
};

static void add_tokens(token_tree *tree, const char **tokens) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++) {
        token_tree_add(tree, tokens[i], strlen(tokens[i]));
    }
}

static void print_tokens(token_tree *tree, const char *text) {
    size_t len = strlen(text);
    size_t token_len;

    printf("input: \"%s\"\n", text);
    printf("tokens: [");
    while(len) {
        token_len = token_tree_longest_token(tree, text, len);
        if(token_len > 0) {
            printf("<%.*s>", (int)token_len, text);
        } else {
            printf("?");
            token_len = 1;
        }
        text += token_len;
        len -= token_len;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

static void run_test(token_tree *tree, const char **texts) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; texts[i] != NULL; i++) {
        print_tokens(tree, texts[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    token_tree *tree = token_tree_new();

    add_tokens(tree, test_tokens);

    run_test(tree, test_input);
    run_test(tree, test_tokens);

    token_tree_free(tree);
}

#endif
```